# Stream write big byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, stream

I am trying to write inside http request stream a huge byte array
this is my code:

```
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(body);

request.ContentType = contentType;
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
stream.Close();
```

It works fine with small files but when I try ti write byte array [9264619]I am getting an abort error.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the exception stack trace.

Comment: 1) probably a configured maximum entity size of the web server is exceeded; 2) you are sending a body as a *request* - in ASCII, in 2017 - what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am using Gmail Api. I need to sent inside request body the Attachment encoded in base64.

Comment: ok. you're likely hitting a size limit, either on the sending side, or on the receiving side. can you do chunking? (splitting the job into several smaller requests)? please include the full exception information in your question otherwise it will be too much guessing.

Comment: Just to be sure, what exactly is the "abort error"?